# qbittorrent fails claiming too many files open

Tags: files, bittorrent

I have a machine running Ubuntu 16.04. It has a 2TB drive with a lot of files, but certainly more than 30% free. Everything was working. I was running qbittorrent. I shut the machine down and didn't bring it up again for a few weeks. After rebooting, qbittorrent fails after about 60 seconds saying there are too many open files.

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

shows 713000

```
sysctl fs.file-nr
fs.file-nr = 9760   0   781241

sudo lsof | wc -l
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system 
   /run/user  /1000/gvfs
   Output information may be incomplete.
133915
```

Under qbittorrent is 17,116 directories, 167826 files. So there are quite a lot. The program crashes on startup so I cannot query it for how many files are open.

This seems like a horrible bug in qbittorrent. Even if they are loading files, they should not open 171k all at once.

Whatever is wrong, I have the same number of files I did when I shut the system down.

Comment: What I'm guessing here is that the message you are receiving is not explicitly about qbittorent rather about the whole system. Check output of these commands and add them to your question: `sysctl fs.file-nr`, `sudo lsof | wc -l` , `ulimit -n` and `ls /proc/$(pidof qbittorrent)/fd/ | wc -l`. (Ping me with @ravexina) to make sure I see your replay (or edit).

Comment: ulimit -n showed 1024. I increased to 16384 and it's working again. @ravexina, I don't know why qbittorrent would try to load 1024 files simultaneously, that seems crazy.